# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list when use data-label

Tags: syntax-error

i use this code for change color of text.

good if i use $("tr:visible td:last-child").each(function() {

but "error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" when use data-label

Example: AAAAA is name of column header

Please look and help

Thanks

```
 //$("tr:visible td:last-child").each(function() {
   $("tr:visible td data-label="AAAAA" ").each(function() {
           if ($(this).text() == "Work") {
          var colorforcell = '<div style="background-color: yellow ">'+$(this).text()+'</div>';
            };
           
            $(this).html(colorforcell);
       });
```

Comment: If strings are in bold, this is treated as: $("**tr:visible td data-label=**"AAAAA" "). AAAAA is treated as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape quotes or use a different kind when nesting them.

```js
   $('tr:visible td data-label="AAAAA"').each(function() {
           if ($(this).text() == "Work") {
          var colorforcell = '<div style="background-color: yellow ">'+$(this).text()+'</div>';
            };
           
            $(this).html(colorforcell);
       });
```

Comment: Thanks, it leads to another error " Syntax error, unrecognized expression"

Comment: If this helped, accept the answer and create a new question for a new error.